# What is lua obfuscation?

Tags: encryption, lua, obfuscation, deobfuscation

Lua obfuscation has been going through my mind all day and I just barely notice that people claim this and that is obfuscation, but what is obfuscation?

**Yes**, I do know that obfuscation is to make your code unintelligble and very difficult to process, thus scaring people who want to skid from your script. But I've seen people  say that this is that is obfuscation so I was going to ask you guys since you are a community full of experts that if you would know if there are actually only one kind of obfuscation and what obfuscation truly means.

This might be a debatable question which is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obfuscation has been a debatable topic for years but never really has drawn attention.

I'm glad to see someone like you to be a little like me, studying obfuscation.

**No**, obfuscation and encryption are two different things. For instance, encryption is a like a door, you cannot access it without the key. Obfuscation is like hiding the key to your door somewhere but is very difficult to find and reach. It all depends on how you make it.

**You are correct**, there is many different types of obfuscation and encryptions. But I'll focus on obfuscation for now. You can use encryptions for obfuscations, you can define obfuscations as encryptions, you can make your own obfuscation. But they all draw to the same thing, it just matters what path you take. The more popular side of obfuscation is probably a virtual machine. Custom built virtual machines allow it to interpret custom bytecode that is invalid when you print it because it's custom and it won't be read correctly. There are good ones out there that are also virtual machine-"d" and they also work differently. Their lbi's could be the same as the one released on GitHub, or could be modified. It could be all fit into one line making it more hard to read. But the thing that matters the most is how you make it.

I hope my answer was helpful!

Comment: How can someone deobfuscate bytecode obfuscation? I only ever managed only to get this out of a bytecode obfuscation : https://pastebin.com/07cMUjcX